# spring & tiles - including .html files

Tags: html, spring, tiles

I've got a spring project using tiles as UI framework. I wanted to provide a generic controller handling static html files (no dynamic content - so no custom controllers). The generic controller is `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController`. The whole thing works for if I put static content in `.jsp` extension files. As long as I try to put them in `.html` - I get 404 error and I want to figure out why.

web.xml:

```
<display-name>
    lyricsBase
</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>lyricsBaseApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>lyricsBaseApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>list.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

lyricsBaseApp-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>

<bean id="staticViewController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController">
    <property name="prefix" value="t." />
</bean>

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/list.html">jukeboxController</prop>
            <prop key="/display.html">songController</prop>
            <prop key="/static/about.html">staticViewController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

tiles.xml:

```
<definition name="t.base" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/base.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="SomeTitle"/>
</definition>

<definition name="t.static/about" extends="t.base">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/static/about.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="title" expression="about"/>
</definition>
```

This is the URL I'm accessing the static page at: `http://localhost:8084/lyricsBase/static/about.html`

I've got both `about.html` and `about.jsp` files in the proper directory. If a

```
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/static/about.jsp"/>
```

to

```
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/static/about.html"/>
```

I start getting the warning in tomcat:

```
2013-02-16 18:21:45 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/lyricsBase/WEB-INF/static/about.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'lyricsBaseApp'
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked 2 years ago, but I encountered the same problem and maybe sometime someone else.

I think Tiles only supports JSP, Freemarker or Velocity. I could find a workaround. Define a static handler like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value = "com.xy"))
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/lyricsBase/static/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/static/");
    }
}
```

now you should be able to use your html template by tiles:

```
<put-attribute name="body" value="/lyricsBase/static/about.html"/>
```